# Is there anything site-specific that can be done about excessive caching?

Tags: feature-request, votes

I just updated a bug report on meta.SE about excessive caching:

[Caching should not show me yesterday's info!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239887/caching-should-not-show-me-yesterdays-info)

I would like to know how many votes I've cast, but I'm still seeing yesterday's vote counts.  Based on the other times I've noticed this, I'm going to continue to see yesterdays's counts for quite a while.

Would a request from a/the mod(s) be able to get the caching turned down a bit?

Comment: DevOps FTW... erm, I mean, All hail our new insect overlords!